# Installing Entity Framework 4.2 in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, installation

Entity Framework templates and menu items generate errors in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on 64-bit XP.

The "Reverse Engineer Code First" menu item in Visual Studio tells me that version 4.0.0.0 of System.Data.Entity.dll cannot be found in the GAC, as do the item templates.

I have run the 4.1 msi, and the 4.2 nuget.  As a result I have versions of the dll in the following 7 locations:

- Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
- Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
- Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\policy.4.0.system.data.entity\v4.0_0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\
- Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\
- Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\
- Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0\
- Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\

Anyone have any suggestions?  Seems to me "Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications" should not be so difficult to install.

Comment: As far as I knew you do not get it installed into your GAC.  The Nuget will place the latest into your project, at least this was the way for version 4.1.

Comment: dll is also in the location that the error messages refer to in the gac

Comment: Ok that is alot weirder than I thought.  Maybe you need to install version 4 first as I only thought that 4.1 and 4.2 were add-on type features for the core of it.

Comment: 4.1 download page says prerequisite is only .NET Framework 4.0, which I think includes EF 4.0.  I can't seem to find a separate download of EF 4.0 that is a final release, not a CTP or RC.

Comment: Repaired .NET 4.0 framework, and applied all outstanding Windows Updates.  No change.  Uninstalled EF 4.1 (and MVC 2; kept MVC 3), also no change.  Installed Windows Management Framework update to get Powershell 2.0, also no change, but it did fix a separate exception generated by the Package Manager Console window.  I'm about to chalk this mess up to an XP x64 problem.  (FYI you have to install the Windows Server 2003 x64 version, there is not an XP x64 version)

Answer (score 4):

Entity framework 4.0 (System.Data.Entity.dll) is part of .NET 4.0. There is no separate download. EF 4.1 ad EF 4.2 are distribution of EntityFramework.dll (not System.Data.Entity.dll). EF 4.2 is only distributed as NuGet and is not installed to GAC.

*Reverse Engineer Code First* is not part of any of these tools. It is part of EF Power Tools CTP 1 which is most probably dependent on EF 4.1 (it was released prior to EF 4.2 and there is possibility that it doesn't work with EF 4.2). This tool itself has no relation to functionality of Entity framework.

Comment: An excellent and most needed explanation, which I greatly appreciate.  This possibly reframes the problem, but does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Install EF6 or so using the nuget command line tool. Then in youe msvs solution explorer Add Reference, Browse to the C:\Workplace\C:\Workplace\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45 then add the .dll, either *SQLEntityFramework.dll or  *EntityFramework.dll file.