# How can I install Entity Framework 4.2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, nuget

This used to be trivial via Nuget but now, I can only find 5.0 in Nuget. How can I specifically install version 4.2? We are trying to upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2 but aren't ready for a major upgrade to 5.0 at this time. This is one of those problems that comes up when they decide to not release MSIs (or at least .ZIPs with DLLs in them, which really is all I need here).

Thanks!

**NOTE:** This is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054790/installing-entity-framework-4-2-in-vs2010). The difference is that I can't find 4.2 in Nuget anymore. At the time of that question, it was easy/obvious to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, you can install an older package by adding `-Version <version you want>` to the the `Install-Package` command. If you take a look at the NuGet gallery; when you select a package, scroll to the bottom, you will find the *Version History*. Here you can select the version you want:[image: NuGet version history]

Clicking one of the versions will show you the package details along with the command to install the selected version.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Check out [this page](https://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0). At the bottom, it lists the older versions of EntityFramewor and, when you click on it, it takes you to the details of that specific version, including the Nuget command to install it. For example, [Entity Framework 4.2.0.0](https://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.2.0.0) can be installed via:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.2.0.0
```

I've not actually done this yet, but I think this is exactly what I was looking for.